# How to get data from a generic http get method which returns Observable<T []> in angular 2 version 0.8

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services

Angular version 8.0.4

How to get data from a generic method which returns an array of Observable type T in angular?
This is the function I have written

Generic method to get data

```
public getData<T> (path: string): Observable<T[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + path).subscribe();
        // return this.data;
        // var ddd: T[];
        // return this.http.get<Observable<T[]>>(this.baseUrl + path);

        // var data: any  = this.http.get(this.baseUrl + path).toPromise();
        // console.log(data)
        // return of(data);
    }
```

This is the calling function

```
getRecords(): Observable<Trailers[]> {

        var k: any = this.httpService.getData<Trailers>("get_trailers");
        console.log(of(k));
        return of()
    }
```

Angular 2 older version had something like this

```
public getObjects<T> (path: string): Observable<T[]>  {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+path)
            .map((response: Response) => <T[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('Retrieved data from: ' + this.baseUrl+path))
            .catch(error => this.handleError(error, this.router));
    } 
What is equivalent in angular 0.8 to this ?
```

Comment: can you try to return only Observable (return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + path)) and then use subscribe in calling function 

this.httpService.getData<Trailers>("get_trailers").subscribe( (t) => {k = t);

Comment: @Nuttertools you mean like `return <Observable<T[]>>this.http.get(this.baseUrl + path);`

Comment: public getData<T> (path: string): Observable<T[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + path);
|

Comment: @Nuttertools above will throw an error since its missing `<Observable<T[]>>` casting and this ` this.httpService.getData<Trailers>("get_trailers").subscribe( (t) => {k = t);` will return  observable not data
```

Comment: `Conversion of type 'Subscription' to type 'Observable<T[]>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`

Answer (score 2):

Angular Version: `8.0.2`

Function can be like,

```
get<T>(id: string): Observable<T> {
   return this.httpclient.get<T>(this.baseUrl+ '/' + id);
}
```

Caller can be,

```
this.service.get<MyModel>(id).subscribe((val:MyModel) => { ... // your business logic });
```

Comment: what is `this.myList[id] = val`

Comment: this is just my usecase implementation, `myList: MyModel[]`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use Observable and Subscribe like this.

Function

```
getTestStatus() :Observable<any[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get(`${this.api}/demo/state`) as Observable<any[]>;
}
```

Calling

```
let result;
this.getTestStatus().subscribe((res) => {
  result = res
  console.log(result);
});
```

Subscribe work like async / await, if u try to print some data from it, you should do in in subscribe

hope this help, if not u should wait another guys.

Comment: this `let result` might not work which version of angular you are using ?

Comment: "@angular/cli": "7.3.9", (typescript)

Comment: u can use var, its just declare variable

Answer (score 0):

Http Get method returns Observables. To read data from Observables, it needs to subscribe. That is why subscribe() method is used here.